# Need to change the Google API Key in a bootstrap theme for using google maps

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get Google Maps location working on my new website. I'm using a Bootstrap theme and I'm not able to figure out how the change the API Key inside there, because I have created one, but if I check the development console always the old API key is used.

Thanks for help.

#### JavaScript

```js
var google;

function init() {
    // Basic options for a simple Google Map
    // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
    // var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.71751, -73.990922);
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.69847032728747, -73.9514422416687);
    // 39.399872
    // -8.224454

    var mapOptions = {
        // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
        zoom: 7,

        // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
        center: myLatlng,

        // How you would like to style the map. 
        scrollwheel: false,
        styles: [
            {
                "featureType": "administrative.country",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "visibility": "simplified"
                    },
                    {
                        "hue": "#ff0000"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

    // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
    // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

    // Create the Google Map using out element and options defined above
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

    var addresses = ['New York'];

    for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
        $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
            var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                icon: 'images/loc.png'
            });
        });
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

#### HTML

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>

<section class="ftco-section ftco-no-pt ftco-no-pb">
    <div id="map" class="bg-white"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: @EternalHour if I'm inserting  ```<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>``` with my API Key to the .js at the bottom of the file there is just a blank white space and the map will disappear.
The web development console is telling me:
```SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' ```

Comment: Update your question with the code where you're specifying the API key.

Comment: @EternalHour just like this (updated). I have also tried to insert the API key variable inside this line ```$.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {```but wasn't able to get it working.

Comment: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` means you have a typo where you're missing a closing bracket or missing something in the code. What line does your console say that's happening?

Comment: @disinfor it's telling me ```SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'```if I'm inserting ```@EternalHour if I'm inserting <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>``` at the top of the file (first line). So this is just need working. But I have no clue where else I can use my API key.

Comment: The biggest thing I just noticed is in your `script` tag, your callback is `initMap` but in your code it's `init`. You're also using jQuery for the `getJSON`. What version of jQuery are you using?